# How do I link to open a pdf in a different tab in React? - it just links back to the same webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make it so that a user can click a button and a pdf of my resume will open in a different tab. When I click the button it just opens the same page and the url has the path for the pdf, but still shows the original page. How can I get it to display the pdf? --I'm using window.open to open the pdf currently

I finished the rest of the website, now when I click on the Download Resume button it says the page cannot be found.

```
const Profile = () => {
    return (
        <section id='profile'>
            <div className="section__pic-container">
                <img src={require("./assets/profile-picture2.png")} alt="Umar Manzoor profile Picture"/>
            </div>
            <div className="section__text">
                <p className="section__text__p1">Hello I'm</p>
                <h1 className="title">Umar Manzoor</h1>
                <p class="section__text__p2">Fullstack Developer</p>
                <div className="btn-container">
                    <button className="btn btn-color-2" onClick={() => window.open('./assets/Resume.pdf')}>
                        Download Resume
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default Profile
```